# Setup Subversion for http checkout (using TortoiseSVN)

Tags: svn

I am new to Subversion, and my project requires that I access my repository through http.

I already created the repository on my hosted server (bluehost, centos7), and I am trying to access it from another computer through http.

From reading some tutorial ([this](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion) among others), I understand that I need to configure subversion.conf file, which should be located on '/etc/httpd/conf.d/'.

When I looked at that location, I didn't see that file. 
In addition, the tutorial says that the configuration file should reference 'mod_dav_svn.so' and 'mod_authz_svn.so' modules.

Talking to support, I understood that subversion was not initialized with mod_dav_svn, so I set it up myself. However, I didn't find the 'mod_dav_svn.so' and 'mod_authz_svn.so' in the '/usr/local/apache/modules/' folder. Instead I found them in the '/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/' folder.

Currently, when I try to access my repository (using TortoiseSVN), I get several kind of errors, depending the url that I try to use (with/without 'trunk' at the end, not sure what I need to use):

- Redirect cycle detected for URL (http://example.com/path/to/repos/RepoName)
- Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' (http://example.com/path/to/repos/RepoName/trunk)

when I checkout the repo locally on the server, I use:
svn co file:///path/to/repos/RepoName/trunk

when I surf to:

- http://example.com/path/to/repos
- http://example.com/path/to/repos/RepoName

I just see the repository created folders (conf,db,hooks,locks). I don't get to see a request for password, or the "Revision 0", or my own repository project.

my "/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf":

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_svn.so

# Add the following to allow a basic authentication and point Apache to where the actual
# repository resides.
<Location /repos>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /path/to/repos/
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repos"
        AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

apache error log:

```
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /path/to/repos/RepoName/trunk
```

I am completely lost. What do I need to do now in order to be able to checkout the repository using TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to connect to my repository from my computer through TortoiseSVN, but it was using svn+shh (using svnserve) and not http.

I wwasn't able to understand the reason for the errors "Redirect cycle detected" and "Unexpected HTTP status 405", but if you are reading this because you are trying to setup a connection to your repository and you receive the same errors, maybe you would like to check the following references, that helped me:

http://mikespicer.net/wp/programming/bluehost-with-svn/
https://serverfault.com/questions/182549/subversion-bluehost-and-tortoisesvn
http://cristianfierro86.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/how-to-set-svn-repository-on-bluehost.html

Answer (score 0):

1. If|when "Redirect cycle detected for" appear for http-based SVN, it means (most time) misconfiguration for location: DAV-served `<Location>` must be pure virtual and does not exist on real filesystem of web-server tree. It *seems* you have `/repos` as real directory inside your Apache's home
2. In case of `SVNPath /path/to/repos/` /path/to/repos/ have to be path to real repository, which exist in `repos/` dir directly, but according to your text

> ... I use: svn co file:///path/to/repos/RepoName/trunk

your repository *may be* deeper, than in `repos/`??? Yo'll have to find location of your repository, fix errors (in common you can't have both repositories `/path/to/repos` and `/path/to/repos/RepoName` at the same time (repository have predefined tree and can't contain at filesystem-level another repository), with `SVNPath /path/to/repos/` you can't have access to more than single repo in `/path/to/repos/`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it was not the right solution for me. I managed eventually to access the repository through a network, by using svn+shh (using svnserve and not http). The error is probably something to do with bluehost, but their support was not giving me an answer why it is happening.